# how to shrink widget and stick on top when scrolling down

Tags: flutter, dart

As shown in the first image, when user scroll down, I want the image, title and subtitle to shrink and stick on top like on the second screen and expand back to original if user scrolling up again. How can I do that? I saw many suggest using SliverAppBar, but initially the content is so big and cannot fit in it and anther problem is I need to animate on scroll as well? Any idea how to implement this?

[image]

Here is the sample code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';


void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: MeditationProgram(),
    );
  }
}

const mockImageUrl =
    "https://media.gettyimages.com/id/1321664779/photo/silhouette-of-young-woman-practicing-yoga-outdoors.jpg?s=2048x2048&w=gi&k=20&c=xMSfPYyI53ehTKElC_cPTWC6qc2SWq76BAK0KrKlQNw=";

class MeditationProgram extends StatelessWidget {
  const MeditationProgram({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      extendBodyBehindAppBar: true,
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
        elevation: 0,
        leading: IconButton(
          icon: const Icon(
            Icons.arrow_back,
            color: Colors.black,
          ),
          onPressed: () {},
        ),
      ),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: SafeArea(
          child: Container(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20),
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            child: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: [
                Stack(
                  alignment: Alignment.center,
                  children: [
                    LayoutBuilder(builder: (context, box) {
                      return Container(
                        width: box.maxWidth,
                        height: box.maxWidth,
                        decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                          image: DecorationImage(
                            image: NetworkImage(mockImageUrl),
                            fit: BoxFit.cover,
                          ),
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                            Radius.circular(30),
                          ),
                        ),
                      );
                    }),
                    ElevatedButton(
                      onPressed: () {},
                      style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                        ),
                        backgroundColor: Colors.orange,
                      ),
                      child: const Text(
                        "Watch Intro",
                        style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.white,
                        ),
                      ),
                    )
                  ],
                ),
                // Green card
                Container(
                  margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 20, bottom: 20),
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
                  width: double.infinity,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: Colors.green,
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
                  ),
                  child: const Column(
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: [
                      Padding(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 8),
                        child: Icon(
                          Icons.celebration,
                          color: Colors.white,
                        ),
                      ),
                      Text(
                        "You successfully completed the meditation program on 25 October, 2023",
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                const Text(
                  "Stress Management with Yoga",
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 30,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  ),
                ),
                const SizedBox(height: 5),
                const Text(
                  "10 Days • 25-30 mins daily",
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 16,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  ),
                ),
                const SizedBox(height: 5),
                const Text(
                  "lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.",
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 16,
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

https://dartpad.dev/?id=146658a479e4acaad48c200f0fd49fc6

Comment: Can you provide minimal reproducible example on https://dartpad.dev/ for us to test?

Comment: @mandy8055 I have updated it with sample code

Comment: You can follow [SliverAppBar](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/SliverAppBar-class.html)